# how to change the value of an element in a list in Io language?

Tags: list, iolanguage

I was wondering how can I change the value of an element in a list in Io language?

```
l := list(4, 6, 3, 8, 10)
list(4, 6, 3, 8, 10)
```

I want to change it to:

```
list(4, 5, 3, 8, 10)
```

One way is to use `insertAt()` and `removeAt()`, But I want to know whether there is another way or not.

```
l removeAt(1)
l insertAt(5, 1)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

`l atPut(1, 5)`

This will replace index 1 with the value 5.

Comment: I did not see it in the slotNames. Actually I was looking for put instead of atPut. Thanks.